# I get this error: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor

Tags: android, menu, android-toolbar, popupmenu, optionmenu

When i start my application on some devices , i got foreclose:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hala.instgram, PID: 24871
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:144)
    at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:238)
    at com.hala.instgram.views.MainPage.showPopupMenu(MainPage.java:440)
    at com.hala.instgram.views.MainPage.onOptionsItemSelected(MainPage.java:299)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2950)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:436)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:196)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:888)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1189)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3121)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4116)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
    at com.android.internal.os.Device.fp(RmluZ2VycHJpbnQgMjAxOTA2MTggWysrLisuLl0gYXJtZWFiaS12N2E6YXJtZWFiaS12N2EgMjMvMi4xLjAvLSBsZ2UvbHYwX3RyZl91cy9sdjA6Ni4wLjEvTVhCNDhULzE3MDU0MTA0NTA3MTI6dXNlci9yZWxlYXNlLWtleXM=:0)
```

I tried android 6 - 7 - 8 , some devices has no problem at all, some has.

Here is the Java code:

```
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainPage.this, view);
    for (int x = 0; x < Splash.main.getMenu().size(); x++) {
        popup.getMenu().add(Splash.main.getMenu().get(x).getText());
    }

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
    popup.show(); // <------------ Here is error trigger!
}


   View buttonAddProduct =  findViewById(R.id.action_menu);
   showPopupMenu(buttonAddProduct);
   return true;
```

I call the **showPopupMenu** function by this and i do check if the anchor if null or not :

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_menu_button:

            View buttonAddProduct =  findViewById(R.id.action_menu_button);
            if(buttonAddProduct == null)
            {
                View buttonAddProduct_this = this.findViewById(R.id.action_menu_button);
                showPopupMenu(buttonAddProduct_this);
            }else{
                showPopupMenu(buttonAddProduct);
            }

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The XML:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_menu"
android:orderInCategory="300"
android:title=""
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
```

I expect to have the 3 dot menu with the popup anchored to it. 
It works on some devices , but not on all devices.

Please advice

Comment: This error happened because `findViewById(R.id.action_help)` return `null`. You should check why it return null

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, the problem is i can not check why, the test is by google console. so i can not have the device and debug. on my PC it works as expected with no NULL value